# How to boot a Linux live USB on a Mac?

Tags: linux, mac, usb, boot, fedora

I have a USB stick with a Fedora 11 live environment on it.
It's booting fine on 3 PCs where I've tried it.

But I can't get it to boot on a Mac (Intel). When pressing the alt key (or command key, I don't remember which one) during startup I can only choose the "Macintosh HD" and the USB stick doesn't appear.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to create an Intel Mac bootable USB stick, it needs to be setup for EFI/GPT. This should work as of Fedora 10, but it's not automatic; you need to create a USB stick specifically configured for this purpose.

According to the [Fedora 10 release notes](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/release-notes/f10/en_US/What_is_New_for_Installation_and_Live_Images.html#sn-Booting_Live_USB_Intel_Apple), you can do this using the `livecd-iso-to-disk` tool like so:

```
livecd-iso-to-disk --mactel /path/to/live.iso /my/partition
```

replacing the path and partition as appropriate. However, [this post](http://katzj.livejournal.com/427577.html?thread=361017#t361017) suggests that the MBR may also need to be cleared (destroying all existing data on the USB disk):

```
livecd-iso-to-disk --mactel --reset-mbr /path/to/live.iso /my/partition
```

Other details on creating a USB stick are in the [Fedora wiki](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_and_use_Live_USB), though curiously nothing about support for Intel Macs. I've had success with this method in the past, though it seems somewhat hit and miss. As far as I know, it's not possible to create a USB stick that will boot on *both* Intel Macs and non-EFI machines.

Comment: I tried `livecd-iso-to-disk --mactel`, but the script told me i had to do `livecd-iso-to-disk --mactel --format` instead, which successfully created a bootable USB stick.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure you can do this directly; you might require something like [rEFit](http://refit.sourceforge.net/) to be able to boot into an Intel Mac with your live usb.

Have a look at the [Myths and Facts About Intel Macs](http://refit.sourceforge.net/myths/) page on their site.

Comment: rEFit can see the key, then I've got a, error about Mac firmware having troubles with USB.

I think I can forget about booting the mac on this USB stick.

Answer (score 2):

You may try to press "E" at startup.
Or see if it is visible as a startup disk (System Preferences » Startup Disk) and boot from there (reboot).

Comment: THIS IS IT. I have been looking for the key to press to invoke the boot from options in a mac.

Answer (score 1):

Some [notes on booting Intel Mac from external USB drives](http://www.tuaw.com/2008/12/18/mac-101-yes-intel-macs-can-be-booted-from-an-external-usb-drive/).

> [it is] possible to boot an Intel Mac from a USB flash drive. That is a bit more involved, and there are several methods. One is [Das Boot](http://subrosasoft.com/OSXSoftware/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=200&products_id=193), a free utility from Sub Rosa that allows you to convert original disks from [DiskWarrior](http://www.alsoft.com/DiskWarrior/index.html), [Drive Genius](http://www.prosofteng.com/products/drive_genius.php), [TechTool Pro](http://www.micromat.com/index.php) and others to a flash drive. Let Google be your friend on this. Many people have put their favorite rescue utility on a bootable flash drive to save them from any problems in the field.
>
> Before you ask; no, USB *does not* support [target disk](http://www.tuaw.com/search/?q=target%20disk) mode -- a sore point for MacBook Air and unibody MacBook owners.

Comment: Good notes.

Unfortunately, Das Boot is not supported for Leopard, and other tools are Mac OS related as far as I read.

Then on the tuaw link, looks like they're talking of USB hard-drives. I'm trying to boot fro a USB flash-drive (no external power source)

Answer (score 0):

The Flash Drive has to have a GUID Partition Table. The Windows7 Tool diskpart finally implemented this or of course MacOSX itself.

Also, the flash drive has to feature a HFS+ filesystem.