# Using an SD card as a "LiveCD" on a MacBook Pro

Tags: linux, mac, boot, sd-card

I have a 4GB SD card on which I'd like to use like a Linux "LiveCD" (except of course it's not a CD) for my MacBook Pro. Any idea how I could do that? I'd prefer to not use rEFIt.

To boot Mac OS from an SD card it needs to have a GUID Partition Table and the OS must be installed on a HFS+ filesystem. I suppose I'd have to mimic a similar setup for Linux.

Comment: this is always my standard "go-to" answer, but why not try virtualbox?  Then you can use the livecd from within MacOS and not worry about booting.

Comment: @calavera: Because VirtualBox won't run in a situation where I can't make it to the login screen. :)

Comment: hmmm... so your os x installation is screwed up?  is that why you're trying to boot linux, to repair your installation?  Or are you trying to boot OS X from the sd card?

Comment: @calavera: no, it's currently not broken, but it could eventually be. I'm also going to use what space is left to bring on a few more programs, and I will probably use it to help other friends with SD slots in case of hardware failure. It's also in part for the kicks.

Comment: Ok, so you're trying to make an sd card OS X "live cd"?  Sounds cool.

Comment: @calavera: OSX "live SD" is easy. It's supported builtin. I've been trying to put Linux on it instead.

Comment: aaaaah ok, that's what I was confused about.  Maybe you could edit your first line to say "*as* a linux livecd" instead of "*like* a linux livecd".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the computer only wants an blessed EFI boot program, so installing rEFIt on the SD card is a viable option. I simply downloaded rEFIt, transferred the `efi` folder to the root of a small (15MB) HFS+ partition, and run `/efi/refit/enable.sh`. Boom! SD card bootable, and rEFIt should know how to handle the OSes on it.

Comment: @calavera: It tells me I can't accept it for 19 hours, so I'll just wait that.

Comment: Can you describe more detailed how you did it?

Comment: @mcb, on which step do you need help? The steps I've listed (create a small HFS+ partition, put rEFIt on it, run the `enable.sh` script) all seem rather sraightforward to me.

Comment: @zneak: How to I create this partition, with the Disk Utility app? I couldn't find an option for HFS+.

Comment: @mcb, it's called "Mac OS Extended (Journaled)" in the Disk Utility. HFS+ is its short name.

Comment: @zneak, Thanks! But one more question: in the tutorial they use `sudo dd if=/path/to/downloaded.img of=/dev/rdiskN` to copy the image to the flash device. Will this step still work or will it override the HFS+ partition?

Comment: @mcb, yes, it will. As I mentioned in my post however, you can just dump the files there yourself (as with `cp` or a drag&drop from the Finder) and it should work as well. Or at least, it did when I tried a year ago.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it has been answered at [How to boot a Linux live USB on a Mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/27794/how-to-boot-a-linux-live-usb-on-a-mac).

Comment: Yeah, the question is quite similar to mine. Though, it's not been answered.

Comment: .. close but it's not quite the same.  Booting from the usb port with a flash drive and booting from the sd card slot with an sd card might be different scenarios.  However, @zneak, I'd encourage you to just try using the same technique as you would use for booting from a flash drive.  you can try setting the sd card as the startup disk in system preferences.

Comment: @calavera: no, can't. It won't list it.